# Finding $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$z=r^3cos^2\theta$$
>   express $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$ by $x$,$y$,$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

I found that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\cdot\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\Rightarrow r^2\cos^2\theta\sin\theta=\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\cdot\sin\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\cdot\frac{\cos \theta}{r}$

And that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\cdot\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\cdot\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\Rightarrow 3r^2\cos^2\theta\sin\theta+2r^2\cos\theta\sin^2\theta=\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\cdot\cos\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\cdot-\frac{\sin \theta}{r}$

How can I continue from here?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your derivatives..

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} = -2r^3\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = 3r^2\cos^2\theta$$

Comment: @1over137 I do not understand I have used the same expression you have wrote, they are wrong?